# python venv not working on second dev machine due to different drive letter

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-venv

#### What I'm trying to accomplish

- Develop a python project on both my desktop and laptop interchangeably using VSCode and python 3.9

#### My environment

- ***env*** virtual environment created and contains all python modules I need (`python -m venv env`)
- On my desktop the project files are on the D: drive. The OS, python and VSCode are on the C: drive
- On my laptop, everything is on the C: drive, i.e., project files, OS, python and VSCode

#### The problem

When I try to run the virtual environment on the laptop I get an error as it tries to run python.exe out of the D: drive instead of the C: drive. as per message below.

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"d:\onedrive\projects\prj - python\musicdb snippets\env\scripts\python.exe"  "C:\Users\chfal\OneDrive\Personal Life\Projects\PRJ - Python\MusicDB snippets\env\Scripts\pip.exe" list modules': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: How did you create the environments?

Comment: I believe this is vscode specific, your .vscode/settings.json saves the `python.pythonPath` variable inside that file and that's what vscode uses when it tries to run. I'd recommend not sharing that between machines and having a unique one per machine.

Alternatively, if your virtual environments are created in the same relative path on both machines you could try updating the pythonPath to use relative pathing.